# TypeScript ':' expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I'm having a problem with TypeScript compiler that expects a `:` in 17, 5 but I can't understand why and where to put it, my code:

```
import { Client , TextChannel } from "discord.js";

module.exports = {
    name: "ready",
    run: async(client: Client) => {
        client.user.setPresence({
            activities: [{
                name: "Aun en beta!"
            }],
            status: "idle"
        })

        let str = `-- censored --`
        let channel: TextChannel; 
        channel = client.channels.cache.get('-- censored --')?
        channel.send (str)
    }
}
```

Comment: `channel = client.channels.cache.get('-- censored --')?` why is there a `?` at the end? Did you want `;` insteand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was with a `?` as mentioned in the comment.
also you forgot many **semicolons** in your code that I added.

I edited your hole code and here it is:

*if you meant a null check by that `?` then you had to place it somewhere else... see this below*

```
import { Client , TextChannel } from "discord.js";

module.exports = {
    name: "ready",
    run: async (client: Client) => {
        client.user.setPresence({
            activities: [{
                name: "Aun en beta!"
            }],
            status: "idle"
        });

        let str = `-- censored --`;
        let channel: TextChannel;
        channel = client.channels.cache?.get('-- censored --');
//                                     ^^                     ^
        //                                            problem was here
        channel.send(str);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of line `channel = client.channels.cache.get('-- censored --')?` due to `?` compiler expect that it as a conditional (ternary) operator (`condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`) so throw `':' expected` error.

May be it's a typo and should be like `channel = client.channels.cache.get('-- censored --');`

Or it should be like `channel = client.channels.cache?.get('-- censored --');`.